# When Xgboost stops growing tree

Tags: boosting

I'm using Xgboost's gradient boosted tree model for binary classification.  It has a `max_depth` parameter, which specifies the maximum depth of each individual tree.  This makes me assume that it can potentially stop splitting and end with a tree that is shallower than the `max_depth` tree parameter.

When building a tree, what stopping condition does Xgboost use to decide when to stop growing the tree (when to stop splitting a particular node any further)?  I checked the original papers and the documentation and couldn't find any description of this.

Answer (score 3):

A split is decided based on the loss it produces. You can see the exact form in equation (7) of [XGBoost: A Scalable Tree Boosting System - Chen, Guestrin](http://XGBoost:%20A%20Scalable%20Tree%20Boosting%20System). Specifically, we look at the drop in loss by doing the split, but then subtract $\gamma$, which is a regularization hyperparameter. In other words if the loss drop exceeds $\gamma$, we honor the split. If not, the split isn't made. I would think then that max_depth is reached only if the sequence of splits exceed $\gamma$ in loss drop. Otherwise if $\gamma=0$ there doesn't seem to be anything preventing the algorithm from attaining max depth.

Comment: Is it really the gain in accuracy?  Gradient boosting generally uses regression trees, which greedily minimize the mean squared error.

Comment: @MatthewDrury: It's formally a lowering of the loss. I was thinking along the lines of classification. Corrected, thanks.